validar y registrar user
soy un poco nueva por aquí.
tengo una relación de empleado y user. donde solo los empleados registrados podran crear un usuario.
como valido esto desde mi formulario de registro y evitar el redireccionamiento de error DB
este es mi registercontroller donde se encuentra el metodo create
protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $personal = Empleado::where('cedula','=',$data['cedula'])->first();

           return User::create([
                'empleado_id' => $personal['id'],
                'username' => $data['username'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            ]);

           
   }


¿Cómo es que has hecho toda la lógica de creación del usuario pero desconoces como validar si está o no logeado? En el login que fue lo que hiciste entonces?

@OCHOA no es el login ... ella creo la logica del backend para que un tercero registre empleados (una burda captura de datos) ... ahora lo que quiere es que solo esos empleados pre-registrados pueda crear un usuario para login, por medio del tecero o por si mismo... como sea ... lo unico que tienes que evaluar es si el empleado existe ... y eso lo hace consultando la base de datos, te recomiendo que lo hagas con el codigo de empleado, DNI o Cedula... con tal de que sea mas facil validar si existe o no  ...

Quien dice que es el login? Pregunto eso porque desde el momento que está desarrollando el modulo de creación de usuarios, ya debe haber un login que maneje que usuarios están o no conectados, esa misma lógica se usa para determinar si el usuario conectado tiene o no permisos para crear nuevos usuarios. Yo no hablo del loggeo general, hablo de "donde solo los empleados registrados podrán crear un usuario" esos empleados "registrados" o con permisos, ya lo debe manejar en algún lado, algo parecido al login. Sesiones y permisos pues...

Lo puedes hacer obteniendo el Rol desde una Sesión o desde la Base de Datos.
A continuación te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo usando Sesión.
<?php

// Obtenemos el rol del usuario desde una función.
$rol_usuario = obtener_rol_usuario();

// Función para obtener el rol del usuario (puede ser de una sesión o una base de datos).
function obtener_rol_usuario() {
    // Ejemplo:
    return $_SESSION['rol'];
}

protected function create(array $data) {
    // Definimos los roles permitidos para guardar datos (si es mas de uno)
    $roles_permitidos = array("administrador", "empleado");

    // Verificamos si el rol del usuario está en la lista de roles permitidos
    if (in_array($rol_usuario, $roles_permitidos)) {
        $personal = Empleado::where('cedula','=',$data['cedula'])->first();

        return User::create([
              'empleado_id' => $personal['id'],
              'username' => $data['username'],
              'email' => $data['email'],
              'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}

?>

Espero que te sirva.

Si esta respuesta te ayudó, por favor márcala como aceptada.
